# Objects rotating and rolling without slipping

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-kinematics

The question below confused the hell out of me. It's pretty much straight forward but until the point of where to use which radius. I know that I'll have to use the formula Tr=Iα and then we simplify T into T = -ma+ma, and α into α = a/r. In which part of the formula should I use the radius of the axle and when should I use the radius of the yo-yo. Thanks in advance. I'll leave you with the question:-

In 1993 a giant 400-kg yo-yo with a radius of 1.5 m was dropped from a crane at a height of 57 m. One end of the string was tied to the top of the crane, so the yo-yo unwound as it descended. Assuming that the axle of the yo-yo had a radius of 0.10 m, estimate its linear speed at the end of the fall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1.5 m radius you'll use for the moment of inertia.  The 0.1 m radius of the axle will relate the linear speed to the angular speed.